# element not visible exception in selenium drop down

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting element not visible exception in carrier drop-down list. I tried implicit wait, explicit wait, and all id, class, XPath, CSS selector way to find the element. Please help me to get to get the right XPath. I have "element not visible" exception error message at select a carrier drop-down list. Thank you .

```
<select class="form-control error" id="smsCarrier" name="smsCarrier" required="" data-required-message="Carrier is required." aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="-1">Select a Carrier</option>
    <option value="@message.alltel.com">Alltel</option>
    <option value="@txt.att.net">AT&amp;T</option>
    <option value="@myboostmobile.com">Boost Mobile</option>
    <option value="@sms.cricketwireless.net">Cricket Wireless</option>
    <option value="@msg.fi.google.com">Project Fi</option>
    <option value="@text.republicwireless.com">Republic Wireless</option>
    <option value="@messaging.sprintpcs.com">Sprint</option>
    <option value="@tmomail.net">T-Mobile</option>
    <option value="@email.uscc.net">US Cellular</option>    

<select class="form-control error" id="smsCarrier" name="smsCarrier" required="" data-required-message="Carrier is required." aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="-1">Select a Carrier</option>
        <option value="@message.alltel.com">Alltel</option>
        <option value="@txt.att.net">AT&amp;T</option>
        <option value="@myboostmobile.com">Boost Mobile</option>
        <option value="@sms.cricketwireless.net">Cricket Wireless</option>
        <option value="@msg.fi.google.com">Project Fi</option>
        <option value="@text.republicwireless.com">Republic Wireless</option>
        <option value="@messaging.sprintpcs.com">Sprint</option>
        <option value="@tmomail.net">T-Mobile</option>
        <option value="@email.uscc.net">US Cellular</option>
        <option value="@vtext.com">Verizon</option>
        <option value="@vmobl.com">Virgin Mobile</option>
    </select>


    I used Fluent wait.

     public void ContinueWhenReady(By locator, int timeout)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
                            IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));

                            break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                        }

                    }
                }

        //PhoneNumberDetails details = table.CreateInstance<PhoneNumberDetails>();

                    ContinueWhenReady(By.CssSelector("#smsCarrier"), 50);
                    var SelectaCarrierDropDown = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#smsCarrier"));
                    SelectaCarrierDropDown.Click();
                    var selectaCarrierElement = new SelectElement(SelectaCarrierDropDown);
                    //selectaCarrierElement.SelectByText(details.SelectaCarrier);
                    selectaCarrierElement.SelectByValue("@myboostmobile.com");
```

Comment: Which Element you are trying to locate?

Comment: Your gonna have to give us a bit more detail if you need assistance Sudeep, what have to tried so far? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Share the selenium code with which you are trying to select the element. Also which element are you trying to select ?

Comment: public void ContinueWhenReady(By locator, int timeout)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {

                try
                {
                    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
                    IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));

                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }

            }
        }

Comment: ContinueWhenReady(By.CssSelector("#smsCarrier"), 50);
            var SelectaCarrierDropDown = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#smsCarrier"));
            SelectaCarrierDropDown.Click();
            var selectaCarrierElement = new SelectElement(SelectaCarrierDropDown);
            //selectaCarrierElement.SelectByText(details.SelectaCarrier);
            selectaCarrierElement.SelectByValue("@myboostmobile.com");

Comment: I am getting element not visible exception in carrier drop down list.Plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned your question isn't really detailed enough to know your exact problem, but there are a couple common ones when working with dropdowns in Selenium that I can point out.

First, you need to make sure the select has actually loaded on the page before you try to find it. So you may need to use a WebDriverWait to do that. Example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("smsCarrier")));
```

Then you can try to locate the dropdown and store it in a WebElement:

```
WebElement carrierDropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("smsCarrier"));
```

The trick is, to work with dropdowns you need to then wrap that WebElement in a Select object:

```
Select carrierSelect = new Select(carrierDropdown);
```

From there you can use methods on that Select object to manipulate it, such as selecting an option from the dropdown. Example:

```
carrierSelect.selectByVisibleText("Boost Mobile");
```

or

```
carrierSelect.selectByValue("@myboostmobile.com");
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

In JAVA you can do something like :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
Select dropdown = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("smsCarrier")))));  
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Cricket Wireless");
```